# Do i need to take care when setting src attribute of an image, where src path is specified by user?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss, sanitization

I am creating a page wherein user will specify the url of an image. This url will be stored in DB, and then it will be retrieve back to display the image. So far it is good if the user is not trying to be mischievous.

But now going by http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html , a user can also specify a url which is actually a script.

```
<IMG SRC=javascript:alert('XSS')>
```

I tried this in a page but this didn' do any harm. [ no alert is shown ]
So the point is, do i really need to care what the user is specifying? If yes, then what are the cases/scenario which i need to consider, and how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you get anything from untrusted source, you need to take care of it. In this case, users can write some harmful code to break your html.

```
<img alt='' src='' />alert('xss');<!--'-->
```

Also user input should be handled in different approaches when being used in different places. E.g. Url encode, Html encode, Javascript encode.

In summary, don't trust user input!

Answer (score 1):

Before storing in database, make sure it is:

1. Valid URL (each server side language has its own methods)
2. Valid image (using some sort of  XMLHTTP/WebRequest in server side and parse the contents)

If you have ASP.NET step #2 become simple matter of creating new Bitmap using the WebResponse stream and see if it's successful and the Bitmap is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Also he could provide a value like `myevilscript.php` where he does some php-stuff. So in fact you really shouldn't do this :)